# Socket.io.js - net::ERR_ABORTED & 404 Not Found

Tags: express, socket.io

i'm new to socket.io. Currently i facing an issue which is socket.io.js not able to access.

I manage to access from my local PC, but when someone connect to my LAN to my PC, it will prompt this error `'net::ERR_ABORTED & 404 Not Found'`.

I notice the issue was `localhost`, when someone else access to your PC localhost script won't work on their side. Besides, i also tested with PHP '`$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`'

server.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

var port = 3005;

io.on('connection',function(socket){
    console.log(socket.id);
});

http.listen(port, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:%d',port);
});
```

client.js

```
<script src="http://localhost:3005/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3005');
     $(function(){
        socket.emit('refresh_list');
    });
</script>
```

If source code require, i'll upload my code to github/bitbucket.

**Version:-**

Node v8.9.4

Socket.io 5.6.0

Express 5.6.0

Answer (score 0):

Change this script tag from this:

```
<script src="http://localhost:3005/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

to this:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

When someone from another PC on the network tries to load that web page, the browser tries to find socket.io.js at `http://localhot:3005`, but when the browser is on another PC, `localhost` is that other PC, not your server and thus it doesn't work.

Removing the hostname from the URL in the `<script>` tag, tells the browser to use the same hostname was that the web page was loaded from which is what you want.

---

You also need to change this:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3005');
```

to this:

```
var socket = io();
```

---

The idea here is that you have to remove all references to `localhost` if you want this to work from other computers.

Comment: I've tested with this method, once i change the script without localhost, it will display 404 and user from other pc will also receiving this error

Comment: @JakeCube - I don't know exactly what you're doing, but you HAVE to remove all references to `localhost` from your HTML file if you want the HTML page to work from other computers.  See what else I added to my answer.  And, please tell us what the URL is in the URL bar in the browser when you attempt to load the web page from the other PC on your network?